# How to test my makefile for all supported configurations?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

As you know, `make` is dynamic and `makefiles` can be written to build for different environments and configurations. How can someone test such `makefiles`? Since its totally infeasible to explicitly run it on each supported environment/configuration?

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is the best you can do; test on as many of the supposedly-supported configurations as you can.